# how can i sum opid where it 30to32 or 15to17 in the same workcenter

Tags: sql-server

I have this table

```
job id  op id   hours_actu   hours_est  hours_plan      work_id
10195   31      0            3.12       3.12            2011
10195   30      2.25         0.67       0.67            3042
10195   31      4.5          3.34       3.34            3042
10195   15      2.25         0.67       0.67            3042
10195   16      4.5          3.34       3.34            3042
```

I need to make query to get data like this

```
job id    30,31_actu 30,31_est 30,31_plan 15,16_actu 15,16_est  15,16_plan  work_id
10195       0         3.12      3.12                                             2011
10195      6.75     4.01        4.01         6.75         4.01             4.01      3042
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about how to dynamically change the column name but i have an idea like keepint an constant column name i had tried like this.

```
select 
x.[job id],
sum(x.[30,31,32_actu]) [30,31,32_actu],sum(x.[30,31,32_est]) [30,31,32_est],sum(x.[30,31,32_plan]) [30,31,32_plan],
sum(x.[15,16,17_actu]) [15,16,17_actu],sum(x.[15,16,17_est]) [15,16,17_est],sum(x.[15,16,17_plan]) [15,16,17_plan],
x.work_id
from
(
select  
a.[job id],a.[op id],
[30,31,32_actu] = (case when a.[op id] between 30 and 32 then a.hours_actu else 0 end),
[30,31,32_est] =  (case when a.[op id] between 30 and 32 then a.hours_est else 0 end),
[30,31,32_plan] =  (case when a.[op id] between 30 and 32 then a.hours_plan else 0 end),
[15,16,17_actu] = (case when a.[op id] between 15 and 17 then a.hours_actu else 0 end),
[15,16,17_est] =  (case when a.[op id] between 15 and 17 then a.hours_est else 0 end),
[15,16,17_plan] =  (case when a.[op id] between 15 and 17 then a.hours_plan else 0 end),
a.work_id
from table1 a
) x
group by x.work_id,x.[job id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this if you wanna name the columns dynamically.............................

```
select * into #table1 from 
(select 10195   [job id],31      [op id],0            [hours_actu],3.12      [hours_est] ,3.12       hours_plan     ,2011 work_id
union all
select 10195   ,30      ,2.25         ,0.67       ,0.67            ,3042
union all
select 10195   ,31      ,4.5          ,3.34       ,3.34            ,3042
union all
select 10195   ,15      ,2.25         ,0.67       ,0.67            ,3042
union all
select 10195   ,16      ,4.5          ,3.34       ,3.34            ,3042) x



declare @t table (col1 int,col2 int)
insert into @t
select y.Col1,z.Col2 from (
select row_number() over (order by x.Col1) rn, x.Col1 from (select distinct b.[op id] Col1  from #table1 b  where b.[op id] between 30 and 32) x) y
full outer join
(select row_number() over (order by x.Col2) rn, x.Col2 from (select distinct b.[op id] Col2  from #table1 b  where b.[op id] between 15 and 17) x) z
on y.rn = z.rn


declare @tab nvarchar(max),@col1 varchar(100),@col2 varchar(100)
set @col1 = substring((select ',' + convert(varchar(10), x.col1) from @t x  for xml path('')),2,100)
set @col2 = substring((select ',' + convert(varchar(10), x.col2) from @t x  for xml path('')),2,100)

set @tab = 'create table #t ( [job id] int, [' + @col1 + '_actu] money, [' + @col1 +  '_est] money, ['   + @col1 +  '_Plan] money, [' + @col2 + '_actu] money, [' + @col2 +  '_est] money, ['   + @col2 +  '_Plan] money, [work_id] int) '
set @tab = @tab + 'insert into  #t  
select 
x.[job id],
sum(x.[30,31,32_actu]) [30,31,32_actu],sum(x.[30,31,32_est]) [30,31,32_est],sum(x.[30,31,32_plan]) [30,31,32_plan],
sum(x.[15,16,17_actu]) [15,16,17_actu],sum(x.[15,16,17_est]) [15,16,17_est],sum(x.[15,16,17_plan]) [15,16,17_plan],
x.work_id
from
(
select  
a.[job id],a.[op id],
[30,31,32_actu] = (case when a.[op id] between 30 and 32 then a.hours_actu else 0 end),
[30,31,32_est] =  (case when a.[op id] between 30 and 32 then a.hours_est else 0 end),
[30,31,32_plan] =  (case when a.[op id] between 30 and 32 then a.hours_plan else 0 end),
[15,16,17_actu] = (case when a.[op id] between 15 and 17 then a.hours_actu else 0 end),
[15,16,17_est] =  (case when a.[op id] between 15 and 17 then a.hours_est else 0 end),
[15,16,17_plan] =  (case when a.[op id] between 15 and 17 then a.hours_plan else 0 end),
a.work_id
from #table1 a 
) x
group by x.work_id,x.[job id]'
set @tab = @tab + 'select * from #t'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @tab




drop table #table1
```